# How to show C_e is closed and not dense in C.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $C_{e}([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of even functions in $C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$

> (a) Show $C_e$ is closed and not dense in $C$.
>
> (b) show the even polynomials are dense in $C_e$, but not in $C$.

I can't start on it... I can't catch any clue..

Comment: What is the metric on your space?  Uniform approximation?

Comment: I cant understand what you mean. What does you intend by 'my space'?

Comment: The space $C_e([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ is a metric space under many metrics.  I assume (but wanted it to be clear) that your intended metric was the sup norm.

Comment: I dont know exact meaning of the sup norm. but when I leanred it in university, the norm of function is defined by its sup on domain. So I guess it is the sup norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume there is a sequence of even functions $f_{i}$ converge to $x$ under $\sup$ norm such that $$\sup |f_{i}(x)-x|<\epsilon$$ for large enough $i$. Then this implies $$\int f_{i}=\int x$$ on $[-R,R]$. But this is impossible unless $\int f_{i}\rightarrow 0$ on $[0,R]$ for any $R$. However this itself is absurd. $(2)$ is similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I show it is a closed set in prob(a).
Using the fact that continuous function makes an image which is compact if domain is compact?

Comment: You only need to show the limit of even functions is even. Assume not and you can prove it without much effort by making use of continuity.